# Create a querystring out of form with jQuery isn't working 

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I want to send an ajax request but the query string I'm trying to build is empty.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>This is a project to show how to use RESTful</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">var contexPath = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";</script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function doAjaxPost() {
    var queryString = $('#htmlform') // empty

    alert("doAjaxPost Called:" + queryString + ":");

    $.ajax({
        ...
        ...
    });
}​    </script>

<H1>Add Employee</H1>

<p>
<form name="htmlform">
<table border=1>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr></thead>

    <tr>
        <td><input  type="text" name="ID" maxlength="5" size="3"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" name="Name" maxlength="10" size="10"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" name="Email" maxlength="10" size="10"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<input type="button" value="Save Employee" onclick="doAjaxPost();" />
<p>
<p>
</form>
[<a href="http://localhost:8080/RESTful/service/employees">List all Employees</a> | <a href="add.jsp">Employee Form Test</a>]
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you get ? `var queryString = $('#htmlform')` should end with a semi colon (`;`)

Comment: @ManseUK. `;` in javascript is optional, read my answer below.

Comment: @gdoron ok thanks (re `;`) .. nice spot with the `name` / `id`

Answer (score 6):

Change from:

```
<form name="htmlform">
```

To:

```
<form id="htmlform">
```

and from:

```
var queryString = $('#htmlform')
```

To:

```
var queryString = $('#htmlform').serialize();
```

Answer (score 3):

You're selecting an HTML object using jQuery but you're not getting anything from it (queryString is still a jQuery object by the time you append it to the url string).

Try the following

```
var queryString = $('#htmlform').serialize();
```

This should result in the form being serialized to a string, at which point appending it should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to say `id="htmlform"` on your form for the `$("#htmlform")` to work.